# php against sql server 2005 is timing out

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2005, timeout

I'm running a php script from the command line against SQL server 2005 using the MS driver for PHP and getting time outs. The query takes about 2 minutes from SQL Server Management Studio and returns > 300,000 rows.

There are multiple queries in the script and for each one I do a `sqlsrv_connect()`, execute the query and then `sqlsrv_free_stmt()` and `sqlsrv_close()`

Output from `sqlsrv_errors():`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08S01
            [SQLSTATE] => 08S01
            [1] => 258
            [code] => 258
            [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Native Client]Shared Memory Provider: Timeout error [258]. 
            [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Native Client]Shared Memory Provider: Timeout error [258]. 
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08S01
            [SQLSTATE] => 08S01
            [1] => 258
            [code] => 258
            [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Native Client]Communication link failure
            [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Native Client]Communication link failure
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08S01
            [SQLSTATE] => 08S01
            [1] => 0
            [code] => 0
            [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Native Client]Communication link failure
            [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Native Client]Communication link failure
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never had much luck getting SQL Server 2005 and PHP to talk using the Microsoft driver, but it worked fine with [PDO's ODBC driver](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php). It might be worth trying.

Simple connection:

```
$host     = '1.2.3.4';
$port     = '1433';
$database = 'MyDatabase';
$user     = 'MyDatabaseUser';
$password = 'MyDatabasePassword';

$dsn = "odbc:DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=$server,$port;DATABASE=$database";

try {
  // connect
  $conn = new PDO($dsn,$user,$password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  // fancy error handling
}
```

Comment: I've moved to PDO for SQL Server, Oracle and ODBC (for Teradata connections).
Only 2 issues I have are:

MS SQL Server driver for PHP used to return rows affected by a query (am working around this by doing a count(*) before and after a table load)

PDO ODBC connection to Teradata has a bug whereby varchar fields > 400 bytes return an empty string and all fields after that in the query are also blanked out. I think this was an old bug that was apparently fixed but I upgraded to PHP 5.3.1 and still encountered it. Workaround for this is to cast all longer varchar fields to a shorter length.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things i can think of.

On the database server have you set up MS SQL to allow remote connections?  If not you will need to do this.

Second are you using Named Pipes or TCP/IP ?

Comment: Remote connections are enable and we're using TCP/IP